# Very strange result with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very good in regex but there is an illogic thing that is happening :
I verified the syntax of a regex with this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BcQfQ/2/ and then replaced the `\d` to another regex to check an url from here : http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls and it's not working : http://jsfiddle.net/bNHQs/2/. And the strangest thing is that when you copy the regex and paste it in a textbox (and then write textbox.value in the code), all is fine : http://jsfiddle.net/6uAQG/2/.

Code of the not working regex :

```
var reg=/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/;
var str="2";
if(str.match(reg))alert("test:true");
else alert("test:false");
```

How can I write the regex in the code so that it works?

Comment: Please post relevant code here (thanks for the JSFiddle too though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape the delimiters ("/") using a backslash. The delimiters mark the begin and the end of the expression. You can only use the slash when you escape it with a backslash. The following expression should work:

```
var reg=/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/;
```

Comment: When you use the text in the textbox it's a string. When you use the expression (note that it isn't surrounded with quotes) it is a special object.  
`typeof("/foo/") == "string"` but `typeof(/foo/) == "object"`. And within a string you don't need to escape the slashes.